# How do you change the font-family of a input element and text with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts

I have a problem with JavaScript that i wrote to change the font in a `<input type="text">` element and a `<p>` element.

```js
function tnrchan() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("pedfields").style.fontFamily = "Times New Roman";
  document.getElementById("preview").style.fontFamily = "Times New Roman";
}

function bschan() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("pedfields").style.fontFamily = "Brush Script MT";
  document.getElementById("preview").style.fontFamily = "Brush Script MT";
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Pick Your Font</legend>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th id="tms">Times New Roman</th>
      <th><input type="radio" id="tmsr" name="font" onclick="tnrchan()" checked="checked"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th id="bs">Brush Script</th>
      <th><input type="radio" id="bsr" onclick="bschan()" name="font"></th>
      <th>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;More Fonts Coming Soon!</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th id="al">Arial</th>
      <th><input type="radio" id="alr" name="font"></th>
    </tr>
    <th id="fs">French Script MT</th>
    <th><input type="radio" id="fsr" name="font"></th>
  </table>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Preview</legend>
  <p id="preview">This Is What Your Words Will Look Like!</p>
  <br>
  <label>Try It Out!<br><input type="text" class="pedfields"placeholder="EXAMPLE..."></label>
</fieldset>
```

I want the font-family of the `<input>` and `<p>` to change to one of the fonts when the functions are called.

Anyone have an idea on what I am doing wrong?

**EDIT** I got it working. It needed the following code:

```js
function changeFont(fontName) {

  var list = document.getElementsByClassName("preview");

  for (i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
    list[i].style.fontFamily = fontName;
  }
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Pick Your Font</legend>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th id="tms">Times New Roman</th>
      <th><input type="radio" id="tmsr" name="font" onclick="changeFont('Times New Roman')" checked="checked"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th id="bs">Brush Script</th>
      <th><input type="radio" id="bsr" onclick="changeFont('Brush Script MT')" name="font"></th>
      <th>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;More Fonts Coming Soon!</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th id="al">Arial</th>
      <th><input type="radio" id="alr" onclick="changeFont('Arial')" name="font"></th>
    </tr>
    <th id="fs">French Script MT</th>
    <th><input type="radio" id="fsr" onclick="changeFont('French Script MT')" name="font"></th>
  </table>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Preview</legend>
  <p id="preview" class="preview">This Is What Your Words Will Look Like!</p>
  <br>
  <label>Try It Out!<br><input type="text" class="preview" placeholder="EXAMPLE..."></label>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: You're using "font-family" instead of "fontFamily".  Dashes are not allowed in identifiers in JavaScript, so the property names exposed by style objects are camel-case.

Comment: What @Pointy said, or you could just add a class instead of changing the style attributes.

Comment: I still can not get it to work. I used this: function bschan()
{document.getElementByClassName("pedfields").style.fontFamily="Brush Script MT";
document.getElementById("preview").style.fontFamily="Brush Script MT";} Do you have any ideas?

Comment: its getElementsByClassName with an 's' in getElements.....

Comment: And it's getElementById with no 's' in getElement

Comment: Thanks guys. I finally got it to work. You were really helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
document.getElementByClassName("pedfields")
```

It says elements, with an **s**, plural.

That returns a NodeList, not an Element. You have to loop over it like an array.

```
.style.font-family
```

Identifiers cannot contain `-` characters. They are subtraction operators. You need to switch to camelCase: `fontFamily`.

Comment: Does document.getElementsByClassName work? i looked it up and it said you need extra JavaScript coding to make it work:http://javascript.about.com/library/bldom08.htm'

Answer (score 1):

Typically, any hyphenated property in CSS is going to be a camelCased property in JavaScript. Thus, you would use `style.fontFamily`.

However, I would recommend switching/applying the class of the element and letting the CSS control the details.